# Não consigo criar um listview no google maps API for Android

Tags: android, listview

Estou criando uma aplicação Android com o `Google Maps API` que me permita mapear problemas de acessibilidade das ruas do Rio de Janeiro.

Meu programa permite hoje que o usuário realize **N** demarcações no mapa, busque um local específico ou faça uma demarcação no local onde o usuário está atualmente (botão `mylocation`).

Estou querendo que, ao clicar em um marcador do mapa, uma `Listview` seja exibida para que o usuário escolha dentre diversas opções qual problema de acessibilidade aquele pedaço de rua possui.

Como implementar `Listview` como retorno de clique em um marcador de mapa?